(IOS) How to get device phone number in flutter
In android for example,
we can get device phone number by executing the code below
_mobileNumber = (await MobileNumber.mobileNumber)!;
but in IOS we can't get phone number by doing this,
how to get device phone number in IOS, flutter?

You have to ask the user to enter their phone number. You cannot obtain it programmatically.

Thank you for answering @Paulw11. umm then can we get the device phone number by another mehod or indirectly? this also impossible?

You are using https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number/example which only supports Android for this function as already declared by them in the plugin page.
Now, for iOS there is no way that works for sure to get simcard number. So, better don't get into workarounds. This is the reason why WhatsApp also asks for the simcard mobile number then validates it by using SMS/Call. Follow the same procedure if you want a verified number. Plus remember that in case of Android this can be faked using and emulator.
